# Enable Apache Felix Web Console to show more than 100 logs

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, felix-dependency-manager

We are using the [Apache Felix Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-web-console.html) to display active bundles, configurations and logs. However, it would be very nice to be able to display more than just the default 100 log entries. Is there a way to configure the console in such a way? I didn't find anything in the official documentation, but this is such a basic requirement that I would guess that there is a solution for this somewhere. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cap is actually not in the web console but in the Log Service itself, which is limited to 100 entries by default. See: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-log.html

To increase this to, say, 200 you can set the following system property:

```
-Dorg.apache.felix.log.maxSize=200
```

If you set maxSize to -1 then you will get an unlimited size log, but beware that it will then grow until you run out of memory.